# How do I perform structural equation modelling with ordinal variables in stata?

Tags: stata, structural-equation-modeling, mediation

I'm doing a summer research project as an undergraduate, and I'm a bit lost with regards to how I should deal with ordinal variables. I'm testing a mediation model with latent variables in Stata, using structural equation modelling. The independent, dependent, and mediator variables are all latent variables with ordinal indicators.

I've found CenterStat's SEM workshop very helpful, but they only discuss continuous variables. From what I've read, I may need to use a different estimator than Maximum Likelihood, or I might be ok to treat my variables as continuous (according to [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/346136331_Why_Ordinal_Variables_Can_Almost_Always_Be_Treated_as_Continuous_Variables_Clarifying_Assumptions_of_Robust_Continuous_and_Ordinal_Factor_Analysis_Estimation_Methods) paper) I'm a bit stuck for where to go next - are there any good resources you might recommend for learning mor about this topic, or about how to go about it in Stata?

Thanks,
Evan

Comment: Check out the `gsem` documentation.

Comment: Never too late to try open source projects like [semopy](https://semopy.com/) or [lavaan](https://lavaan.ugent.be/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question about ordinal indicators, and one that's usually not very well understood in terms of assumptions when we use Likert-type indicator variables. In brief, if you want to estimate a model that accounts for the non-continuous nature of the indicators you can use Stata's gsem command, which can also be invoked in the SEM model builder within Stata. Usually though you're right that most people treat such data as continuous and then use robust estimators such as MLR. You can request this within Stata if you'd like.